# How to show list of product in row change as per range slider which starts with 6 and ends 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have image gallery in 6 images in one row, I want to reduce the number of image in a row as I change range slider from 6 to 5,4,3,2,1 vice versa and this should happen with smooth transition.

This is my range slider and below that HTML code for image grid

```
<input type="range" id="thumbnailSlider" min="1" max="6" value="" start="6" />
<div class="image-grid">
<div class="image-column">
     <img href="productDetails-image.html" class="" src="../assets/img/designs/A-ancient-design-pattern_1.jpg">
      </div>
<div class="image-column">
      <img class="" src="../assets/img/designs/Animal-paw-design-and-orange-texture-pattern_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-column">
      <img class="" src="../assets/img/designs/Beautiful-geomectric-design-pattern_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-column">
      <img class="" src="../assets/img/designs/Big-dahlia-and-narcissus-flowers-on-a-mint-green-background_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-column">
      <img class="" src="../assets/img/designs/Blue-background-with-poinsettia-flowers-design_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-column">
       <img class=""src="../assets/img/designs/Blue-banda-background-with-fountain-like-designs-pattern_1.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post the code of Javascript/Jquery that have you tried..?

Comment: I tried few things to get desired result but didnt work , so i deleted the code not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [`:gt`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) jquery selectors

```js
$('#thumbnailSlider').on('input', function() {
  $('.image-column').css('flex-basis', 100 / this.value + '%')
}).trigger('input')
```

```css
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  j
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) 100ms;
}

.image-column {
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1) 100ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" id="thumbnailSlider" min="1" max="6" value="" start="6" />

<div class="image-grid">
  <div class="image-column">
    <img class="" src="//via.placeholder.com/100?text=1">
  </div>
  <div class="image-column">
    <img class="" src="//via.placeholder.com/100?text=2">
  </div>
  <div class="image-column">
    <img class="" src="//via.placeholder.com/100?text=3">
  </div>
  <div class="image-column">
    <img class="" src="//via.placeholder.com/100?text=4">
  </div>
  <div class="image-column">
    <img class="" src="//via.placeholder.com/100?text=5">
  </div>
  <div class="image-column">
    <img class="" src="//via.placeholder.com/100?text=6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how to make image to acquire remaining space for example if there is one image in row then it should show full width 100%, 2 image per row it should be 50% 50% each ??

Comment: but here you are hiding images we need to push that image in next row

Comment: Excellent this is what i wanted.. Thanks buddy